# How to pass the arguments onclick event jquery

Tags: jquery

i am getting json file data on ready event

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $.getJSON( "data/wall.json", function( data ) {
            createWall(data);
        });
    })

    function createWall(data)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var stats = $("<p class='meta'><span>14 Days Ago</span><span class='comments' onclick='commentSection("+data[i]+")'>0 Comments</span><span class='likes'>Like</span></p>");
    $('#wall').append(stats);
}
    }

    function commentSection(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
```

Here when i click on comments. It shows Unexpected identifier .
How to pass particular data by onclick event

Comment: Everything working fine. I can't use onclick with arguments. But It called without argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more appropriate solution will be is to use event delegation and data api like

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.getJSON("data/wall.json", function (data) {
        createWall(data);
    });

    $('#wall').on('click', '.comments', function () {
        var data = $(this).closest('.meta').data('walldata');
        commentSection(data);
    });
})

function createWall(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var stats = $("<p class='meta'><span>14 Days Ago</span><span class='comments'>0 Comments</span><span class='likes'>Like</span></p>").data('walldata', data[i]);
        $('#wall').append(stats);
    }
}

function commentSection(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail sorry... fixed a but in reading the data... it should have been `var data = $(this).closest('.meta').data('walldata');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : put quotes around data using escape character.

```
function createWall(data)
{
        for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var stats = $("<p class='meta'><span>14 Days Ago</span><span class='comments' onclick='commentSection(\""+data[i]+"\")'>0 Comments</span><span class='likes'>Like</span></p>");
    $('#wall').append(stats);
   }
}
```

Comment: It passing [object Object] . Not a values

Comment: to pass value you need to use `data[i].property`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar , dont u think event delegation is better solution?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird, yes it is better solution as suggested by Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly Changes by me, I have passed the data in `data-` attribute and define a event with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on `.comments` class :

```
var stats = $("<p class='meta'><span>14 Days Ago</span><span class='comments' data-clk='"+data[i]+"' >0 Comments</span><span class='likes'>Like</span></p>");

$('body').on('click', '.comments', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 

   // Retrive Data
   var data = $(this).data('clk');
})
```